# Difficulty w/ .desktop file permissions in dock customization

Tags: permissions, quicklists, dock, administrator

I am trying to edit the .desktop files for my docked apps such as:

```
~/.local/share/applications/libreoffice-startcenter.desktop
```

However, I can't get permission for to edit the file. How do I change these permissions?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are asking:

`sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.local/share/applications/libreoffice-startcenter.desktop`